# Best way to make this Apple Script play a specific portion of a song in iTunes?

Tags: applescript

I want iTunes to play a specific 60 seconds of every song in a playlist (say seconds 60-120). What's the applescript code to accomplish this? So far I have:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    repeat with i from 1 to count tracks of playlist "My Playlist"
        play track i of playlist "My Playlist"
    end repeat
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
tell application "iTunes"
    set trackCount to count of tracks of playlist "My Playlist"
    repeat with i from 1 to trackCount
        play track i of playlist "My Playlist"
        set player position to 60
        repeat until player position ≥ 120
            delay 0.5
        end repeat
    end repeat
end tell
```

Comment: +1. But really, instead of 'repeat with i from 1 to trackcount' and 'play track i of playlist "My Playlist"' it should just be 'repeat with theTrack in tracks of playlist "My Playlist"' and 'play theTrack'.